# « à minuit trente précises » ou bien « à minuit trente précis »

Tags: accord

> {j’ai dit} : Je suis rentré chez moi à minuit trente **précises** cette nuit.

... Puis ma collègue m’a fait remarquer qu’il fallait plutôt dire « à minuit trente **précis** ». Pour moi, « à minuit trente précises » est assorti d’un *invisible* mot « minutes ». C’est ce pourquoi je penche pour « précises ».

Notre discussion tourne en rond là-dessus...

Comment: Tu peux aussi avoir pour argument plus judicieux que minuit (et donc minuit trente) est une heure, et ainsi utiliser "à minuit trente (à cette heure) **précise**." Bien entendu, le plus simple est tout simplement d'utiliser l'adverbe "à minuit trente **précisément**". Dans tous les cas, cela va dans ton sens si tu remplace "minuit trente" par "huit heures" (plusieurs heures).

Comment: Attention car *minuit* et *midi* doivent a priori amener l'accord au masculin (*minuit précis*, *midi tapant*, *quatre heures sonnées*, *une heure sonnante*, *deux heures trente passées*). Avec la possibilité de considérer des participes présents (*trois heures tapant*). En revanche, je ne trouve aucun exemple avec *midi* ou *minuit* suivi des minutes.

Comment: Je trouve que `Je suis rentré chez moi à minuit trente précis cette nuit.` sonne mieux, et permet de ne pas confondre avec une seconde proposition autour du verbe préciser.

Comment: À noter que ceci dépends de la région. Au Québec on dirait plutôt précises.

Comment: Guillaume, peut-être qu'on dit "précises" au Québec, mais regarde ce lien: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2892 Ce n'est pas parce qu'on le dit que c'est correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On doit dire normalement je pense: *à minuit trente précis*.

Bien qu'on fasse la faute, par similarité avec: *à deux heures trente précises*
http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9cis

Citation:

> Il n'est pas question de modifier le programme qui invariablement et
>   quoi qu'il arrive commence **à deux heures précises**

http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2892

Citation:

> Précis est un adjectif qui s’accorde avec le mot heure(s) qu’il
>   qualifie. On écrira minuit précis et midi précis puisque ces noms sont
>   au masculin singulier.
>
> - Le 31 décembre **à minuit précis**, c’est le début d’une nouvelle année.

Donc je pense qu'il en est de même pour *minuit trente précis*.

Comment: À 963f2LBU14, on dit s'accorde avec le nom qui précède quand précis suit une indication d'heure, sauf qu'on ne présente pas d'exemple avec minuit et des minutes; mais on donne _trois heures bien sonnées_ et dans ce cas il n'y a qu'un seul nom possible. Mais techniquement, si on disait _minuit trente minutes_, le nom qui précèderait serait _minutes_, sauf qu'ici on ne le dit pas et donc c'est _minuit_. Bien intéressant !